# IBOutlet is nil Xcode 7 for ViewControllers

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

When I create a new NSVC sub-class and add some IBOulets to it, they're always nil when I try to access them. I've tried creating a new project and just one VC class with one just Outlet, and it's still nil.

I've checked that they are indeed connected. I've tried instantiating the class with full nib name. I've also cleaned the project, and trashed the derived data. None made a difference.

So what could be causing this? It's happing with all new projects; I added new outlets to my old project and they work fine. All the IBOutlets are nil, not just selected few. I'm on Xcode 7.1.1.

The error I get is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: When you are testing for the outlets, are you testing during or after `viewDidLoad` is called?

Comment: @ThomasW I've tried during and after, both are nil. I just re-created the whole class, and now I can change the value in `viewDidLoad`, but if I try to access it anytime after that, it's nil.

Comment: How are you loading the view controllers?

Comment: @ThomasW It's set as the `contentViewController` of a Popover, so I don't do it myself.

Comment: Is there any more information about the fatal error, like a backtrace?

Comment: @ThomasW sorry for the late reply. I really appreciate you looking into this, but I found a way around. As you know that the VC was for a popover, so I manually get the `contentViewController as! MyCustomVCClass` rather than using the IBOutlet connected to the VC object from window's xib file (responsible for showing/hiding the popover). I also had to call the `viewDidLoad` function everytime to update it. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not a method that you usually call directly, so I suspect something is wrong here.

Comment: @ThomasW I know, I don't like calling it manually either, but it seems to fix the issue. Couldn't find a possible cause/issue for it, so gonna have to stick with this _"hack"_ until then.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, was there a better solution found?

Comment: @RhuariGlen I don't think so. I don't remember tbh it was a long time ago and I've since then given up iOS development...

Comment: @user14492 No problem, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around if anyone else is facing similar problem. The IBOutlet was nil because it's super view was never loaded so, the app never created it. A simple hack is writing this before using any sub-views:

```
let view = viewController.view
```

This creates the view hence all the outlet on it.

**P.S.** I know it's not a real solution, but I couldn't think of another one. If anyone got any suggestion feel free to post.

Comment: For me this approach is fine, for testing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to access outlets in an init method, or from an accessor when a value is set, before the view has loaded. There are two approaches to handle this situation.

The first is to defer updating the subviews until after you know the view has loaded. I do this by calling an `updateView()` method from `viewWillAppear()`. I also usually call this method when variables get changed, so I test to make sure the view has loaded before I continue. There's no value in setting the views if they don't exist yet. It looks something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var product: Product {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateView()
    }

    private func updateView() {
        guard isViewLoaded() else {
            return
        }

        if let product = product {
            productNameLabel.text = product.title
        }
    }
}
```

The other option, which is similar to what you're doing, is to force the view to load early. I think this is less desirable, but in some cases it's the right approach. But instead of doing it the way you discovered, do it more intentionally like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var product: Product {
        didSet {
            loadViewIfNeeded()
            productNameLabel.text = product.title
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!
}
```